# Flatten/Chain multiple nested firebase Observables

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable, rxjs5, angularfire2

I'm trying to use AngularFire2. I am querying and everything works fine below.

I want to combine all/most of the observables into one:

```
getTournamentWithRounds(key):Observable<Tournament> {

    return this.af.database
        .object(`/tournaments/${key}`)
        .map(tourney => {

            let t = Tournament.fromJson(tourney);

            this.af.database.list('players', {
                query: {
                    orderByChild: 'tournament_key',
                    equalTo: key
                }
            })
            .map(Player.fromJsonList)
            .subscribe(ps => { t.players = ps; });

            this.af.database.list('rounds', {
                query: {
                    orderByChild: 'tournament_key',
                    equalTo: key
                }
            })
            .map(Round.fromJsonList)
            .subscribe(rs => { t.rounds= rs; })

            return t;
        })
  }
```

I was wondering if I could join all the observables and get the output with a single subscribe function.

I would like to know when all the initial data has been loaded and perform additional computation in the controller before outputting it to the view.

Also, how could this be extended to include the matches for each round?

My extension to the above code would be:

```
...

this.af.database.list('rounds', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'tournament_key',
        equalTo: key
    }
})
.map(rounds => {
    return rounds.map((round) => {

        let r = Round.fromJson(round);

        this.af.database.list('matches', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'round_key',
                equalTo: round.$key
            }
        })
        .map(Match.fromJsonList)
        .subscribe(matches => { r.matches = matches; })

        return r;
    })
})
.subscribe(rs => { t.rounds= rs; })

...
```

Comment: I've edited your question to separate your modification to the question's original code. After accepting the answer, you modified the question in such a way that the answer no longer correctly answered the question. I think that should be avoided, as the Q/A won't make sense to anyone else.

Comment: That's ok. My bad. 
Would avoid that. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `combineLatest` operator to combine the players and rounds with the tournament:

```
getTournamentWithRounds(key): Observable<Tournament> {

  return this.af.database
    .object(`/tournaments/${key}`)
    .combineLatest(
      this.af.database.list('players', {
        query: {
          orderByChild:'tournament_key',
          equalTo: key
        }
      }),
      this.af.database.list('rounds', {
        query: {
          orderByChild:'tournament_key',
          equalTo: key
        }
      })
    )
    .map(([tourney, players, rounds]) => {

      let t = Tournament.fromJson(tourney);
      t.players = Player.fromJsonList(players);
      t.rounds = Round.fromJsonList(rounds);
      return t;
    });
}
```

Whenever any of the observables emits, the latest values will be re-combined and a new `Tournament` will be emitted.

Extending this to include each round's matches is a little more complicated, as each round's key is needed for the matches query.

The emitted rounds can be mapped to an array of list observables for the matches and `forkJoin` can be used to join the observables, with the `forkJoin` selector function being used to combine the matches with the rounds. `switchMap` is then used to emit the rounds.

```
getTournamentWithRounds(key): Observable<Tournament> {

  return this.af.database
    .object(`/tournaments/${key}`)
    .combineLatest(
      this.af.database.list('players', {
        query: {
          orderByChild:'tournament_key',
          equalTo: key
        }
      }),
      this.af.database.list('rounds', {
        query: {
          orderByChild:'tournament_key',
          equalTo: key
        }
      })
      .switchMap(rounds => {
        Observable.forkJoin(
          rounds.map(round => this.af.database.list('matches', {
            query: {
              orderByChild: 'round_key',
              equalTo: round.$key
            }
          }).first()),
          (...lists) => rounds.map((round, index) => {
            let r = Round.fromJson(round);
            r.matches = Match.fromJsonList(lists[index]);
            return r;
          })
        )
      })
    )
    .map(([tourney, players, rounds]) => {

      let t = Tournament.fromJson(tourney);
      t.players = Player.fromJsonList(players);
      t.rounds = rounds;
      return t;
    });
}
```